# Substantivierte Verben

Tags: verb

*Ich mag das Seriengucken.
Ich mag Seriengucken.
Ich mag es, Serien zu gucken.
Seriengucken mag ich.*

Wie soll man solche substantivierten Verben schreiben?
*Ich mag das Pizzaessen.
Ich mag das Fußballspielen.*

Comment: Könntest Du präzisieren, was genau Du wissen willst? Ob man sie groß schreibt? Wie man den Satz drumherum formuliert?

Comment: *Wie soll man solche substantivierten Verbe schreiben?* Was genau ist den unklar? Die Groß- und Kleinschreibung? Getrennt- und  Zusammenschreibung? Mit oder ohne bestimmten Artikel? Etwas anderes?

Comment: Alles, was du erwähnt hast. Aber am meisten interessiert es mich, ob ich sie mit Artikeln verwenden muss.

Answer (score 2):

Ich verstehe nicht ganz, was unklar ist. Solche Wörter werden aber groß geschrieben - wie alle Substantive - und sind üblicherweise neutral (das). Sätze wie "Ich mag das Pizzaessen" sind aber von der Form her eher untypisch, in einem Gespräch würde man eher "Ich esse gerne Pizza", "Ich mag Pizza gerne" oder einfach "Ich mag Pizza" sagen. "Das Pizzaessen" ist ein eher ungewöhnliches sunstantiviertes Verb, weil es ein Substantiv mit einem Verb kombiniert. Ist möglich, aber typische Beispiele wären vielleicht eher "das Laufen", "das Lachen", "das Berechnen", "das Flüchten". Man kann etwas Ähnliches wie substantivierte Verben mit "-erei" bilden, diese Wörter sind dann weiblich. Beispiele: "Schlägerei", "Lauferei", "Streiterei". Ansonsten ändert sich an der Schreibweise des Wortes normalerweise nichts.